# Motion blur compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes, motion-blur

Motion blur in compositor doesn't blur poles. It is not the fault of the material because base of the pole has the same material and it is blurring just fine.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I found the answer you need to change min speed to 5 and max speed to 200 in vertex blur node in compositor and it fixes everything

Comment: If you found a solution, please write it on the answers section so 
that other users with a similar question can learn from your 
experience. Read:
[Can I answer my own question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Also, don't forget to accept your answer. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I Wrote the answer I changed min speed to 5 and max speed to 200.

Comment: That's just a comment, scroll down to the answers section -> "Your Answer". Again, I'd suggest take the tour to learn about how this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer you need to change min speed to 5 and max speed to 200 in vertex blur node in compositor and it fixes everything